# Storing Urdu characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I am having problems storing urdu characters in Mysql table. Values from HTML form are stored in tables but when I view in phpmyadmin, it shows weird characters.

I have tried ucs2 and utf8 collations but still new values which I store are unknown characters.

What is the correct collation type? Or is there anything else that is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Check your connection or just set it to be utf-8 http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Don't use ucs2.  If you have further troubles, start a new question, supply `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and your connection parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your column as utf8-utf8_general_ci like this if you are using MySQL workbench.

[image]

Then you will be able to save urdu characters

[image]

Recommend using utf8_unicode_ci for accuracy