# Data type for characters in another language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqldatatypes, mysql2

I have a `Location` table in activerecord which contains the `string` type column `address`. I want to store this **Garden Village Restaurant-B مطعم حديقة فيلاج sub-B** in `address` column, which datatype should I use?
I have already tried `text` datatype but whenever i try to store it gives me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x85\xD8\xB7\xD8\xB9...' for column 'address'
```

Or if there is another way, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate migration: (Why? - Do not run custom queries on your database, as they are not recorded in your schema)

```
rails g migration change_collation
```

Add code as below in migration generated. This will change the character set of database(so next migrations will automatically respect the new collation) and will change the character set of existing tables.

```
class ChangeCollation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change_encoding(encoding,collation)
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    tables = connection.tables
    dbname =connection.current_database
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER DATABASE #{dbname} CHARACTER SET #{encoding} COLLATE #{collation};
    SQL
    tables.each do |tablename|
      execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE #{dbname}.#{tablename} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET #{encoding} COLLATE #{collation};
      SQL
    end
  end

  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        change_encoding('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci')
      end
      dir.down do
        change_encoding('latin1', 'latin1_swedish_ci')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I think `utf8_general_ci` will also support storing the urdu characters. But based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438961/1376448), better to go ahead with `utf8_unicode_ci`

Another way: save address in encrypted manner:

config/initializers/encrypter.rb

```
encrypter_key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new('mypassword').generate_key('a..z', 32)
ENCRYPTER_CRYPT = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(encrypter_key)
```

in model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :encrypt_address
  def encrypt_address
    self.address = ENCRYPTER_CRYPT.encrypt_and_sign(self[:address]) if self[:address].present?
  end

  def address
    # override getter to decrypt and give original urdu string.
    ENCRYPTER_CRYPT.decrypt_and_verify(self[:address]) if self[:address].present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there another way to do that as I don't want to change the encoding of whole activerecord. Like if I could encode the address before saving it and than decode it when i retrieve from activerecord.

Comment: technically, ActiveRecord is not involved here at all. activerecord is just a relational mapper over your database to represent it as objects. The problem is actually *with* your database's encoding. You cannot encode an already encoded urdu string and save it in other form. that's why, you will need to allow your database and tables to start accepting that encoding.

Comment: if there is a particular column, what you can probably do is encrypt the information before saving and decrypt it back when you retrieve it. Not sure if it's recommended though.

Comment: @Touqeer: I added the possible approach of saving address in an encrypted manner before saving to database, and override the getter to decrypt the information before retrieving it. Though, please note that the entire lifecycle can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following command on your desired table(s):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Also delete all the data first from that table 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to lose all my data.